# sum of table's column return null (codeigniter) using left join

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this query:

```
$get_similar = $this->db->select('product.ar_id, product.title, likes.id, SUM(likes.up) as vote');
$get_similar = $this->db->from('product');
$get_similar = $this->db->join('likes', 'likes.id = product.id', 'left');
$get_similar = $this->db->where("MATCH (product.title, product.introduction) AGAINST ('$search') group by product.id LIMIT 6", null, false);
$get_similar = $this->db->get();
```

For each row I get `vote = null`! It's supposed to return `0` for only the products that don't have votes! Can you tell me where I made a mistake, please?

Comment: can you show the var_dump of $get_similar after the get()?

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is here:

```
$get_similar = $this->db->join('likes', 'likes.id = product.id', 'left');
```

you are joining likes.id with product.id, i think you want to join something like "likes.product_id" with "product.id"